# pd.read_html mangles a table header, and adds the entire content of an inner table in the top cell

Tags: html, pandas, dataframe, data-conversion

This is a minimal example of a webpage that pandas is mangling.

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div>
                    <span>Header</span>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Qu2</td>
                            <td>23-09-13</td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           
                            <td>Br</td>
                            <td>R72</td>\n
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this is what the html looks like
[image]

however `pd.read_html` (with all possible flavors 'bs4' 'lxml'...)
gives this

[image]

As you can see, the entire data is also scrunched up in the first cell.

Is there a workaround?
Is this WAI?

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested table as you can see with the nested `<table>` tags in you HTML. Reading the provided HTML `pd.read_html()` returns a list with 2 DataFrames. Simply select the 2nd DataFrame which is the inner list.

```py
df = pd.read_html("<HTML STRING>")
df = df[1]
```

This will give you the DataFrame you are looking for.

Comment: but I don't know how many inner tables I have. and I want them rendered like tables, like they show up on the page.. 
the outer table is also the oe I'm looking for, I just don't want all the spilled contents of one table going to the rest .

Comment: The outer table holds nothing but the table header "Header" for the first column and as first entry it holds the inner table. What information from the outer table actually is important for you? I don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish